# Why does adding a covariate of  age cause variance of random slope (log time) to increase?

Tags: random-effects-model

Why does adding a covariate of age cause the variance of random slope (log time) to increase?
Isn't it supposed to decrease when a covariate is added?

Firstly, there is only $log(time)$ in the model with random intercept and random slope.

$Y=(b_0+e_{b0})+(b_1+e_{b1})*log(time)+e$

Then I add age as covariate:(also with random intercept and random slope)

$Y=(b_0+e_{b0})+(b_1+e_{b1})*log(time)+b_2*age+e$

I found that the variance of the random slope in the first model is even smaller than it is in the 2nd model.

I am very confused, is it necessarily true that adding a covariate into the model will lead to smaller variance of random slope?

Is there any possible explanation?

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, your model & your goals? I'm not sure if this question is answerable in its current form.

Comment: Age and time can often be fairly correlated, so you might be running into a multicollinearity issue, which will cause the error error to go up. This happens because you have very little independent variation in log(time).

Comment: I doubt that this is a general phenomena. It probably is just a consequence of the given data set.

Comment: I know of no reason why this should be required.

What are age and time? As @DimitriyV.Masterov said, they could be collinear.